# How to force windows event mouse plug?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, mouse

I have a dazz mouse gamer connected on pc, always when I restart my computer I loose my mouse configs.

I realised that When I unplug the mouse from pc and plug again the mouse driver detects the event and run configs well.
So I'm looking for a way to force this event of unplug/plug without do it manually, any idea?

Obs: I tried that using devcon.exe restart command, but did not work.

Comment: You have a badly designed hub. Normal hubs, upon disconnect and connect again, would disable all downstream ports, and enter default (unnumerated) state. So the PC will discover the hub again, and re-discover all downstream-attached devices.  Something must be wrong with implementation of VBUS sense in your switch/hub. Get a better hub, or a dedicated "switching hub".

Comment: It's bad, but I have the same problem when I connect the mouse on pc. Always when I restart I need to reconnect the mouse.

Comment: After your edit: what exactly do you mean "when I restart my computer"? In modern days there are several "off states" of a PC, "hard off", "soft OFF', hibernate, standby, "modern standby", sleep, etc.  Also I assume you use a proprietary driver if you have the "mouse config".  Then it is most likely that you have a badly-written driver if it does not restore device configuration after "soft reconnect".

Comment: I have a mouse gamer, and I set up on its softwate a red light for my custom DPI. But everytime that I restart my computer, the mouse comes with green light (default) and a lateral button oppening windows (explorer.exe). So, the only way that fix is mannualy unplug and replug the mouse on usb port again. I tried restart-device using PnPUtil.exe, but didn't work.